# Swift JSONDecoder replace all missing keys by default value?

Tags: json, swift

I want to set up a remote configuration file for staged feature releases, seasonal changes, offers etc. that wouldn't be worth going through App Review for.

I used to use a `\n` separated text file but for multi-line strings this gets a bit awkward real quick.

Instead of importing some bloated framework like Firebase for this, I am currently writing a small singleton that parses a configuration file from a remote URL.

I am however facing one issue now:

If the remote json contains a key that's not defined in my Codable struct everything works fine, I still get my object with all the defined keys. Not so much the other way around, if the json is missing a key defined in the struct, JSONDecoder is not able to decode. Example:

```
    let testJSON = """
{"version":1,"includedB":"B","___notIncludedC":"C"}
"""

struct DefaultConfiguration : Codable {
    var version = 1
    var includedB = "2"
    var notIncludedC = "3"
}
```

I can make the decoding """work""" by defining the notIncludedC to be of an optional `String?` - this however makes the result be `nil` after decoding instead of keeping its predefined default value.

All the answers on SO mention defining custom methods for each key, but I would rather like to use a "skip unknown and keep the value" approach because for big JSON's that would come with a lot of overhead code.

Comment: You will have to write your own decoding init. The synthesised `Decodable` conformance won't do what you need, so you will have to write it yourself. It shouldn't take much code to do anyways

Comment: Making optional properties optional is the most straightforward solution imo.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I was about to move to that solution now but I just found out that then, the property of the struct will be `nil` instead of the default value. Like I'm okay with optional values now but it still gives me nil then whereas I'd like to simply keep the predefined value. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a it was described in the comments you will have to write your own init() since the synthesized one can not provide the behavior you need:

```
let testJSON = """
{"version":1,"includedB":"B","notIncludedC":"C"}
"""

struct DefaultConfiguration : Codable {
    var version = 1
    var includedB = "2"
    var notIncludedC = "3"

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case version
        case includedB
        case notIncludedC
     }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        version = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .version)
        includedB = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .includedB)
        notIncludedC = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .notIncludedC) ?? "3"
    }
}
```

Comment: It sucks that there are no other solutions to this apparently, thank you for taking your time with that!